# Create columns in a data frame from a chracter vector in R

Tags: r

I want to add columns to a data frame (df) based on elements in a character vector, automatically using a function. These new columns are just repeats of zero's.

here's the code to create df:

```
var <- factor(c(a <- rep("a", 20), b <- rep("b", 20), c <- rep("c", 30), d <- rep("d", 30)))
var1 <- factor(c(e <- rep("a", 30), f <- rep("b", 30), g <- rep("c", 20), g1 <- rep("d", 20)))
x_df <- data.frame(var = var, var1 = var1)
```

here's the vector with variable names:

```
names_vec <- c("XA101", "XB101", "XC101")
```

I have manually added these 3 variables with repeats of 0's.

```
x_df$XA101 <- rep(0,nrow(x_df))
x_df$XB101 <- rep(0,nrow(x_df))
x_df$XC101 <- rep(0,nrow(x_df))
```

Desired output:

```
head(x_df) # after adding the 3 variables manually.
```

[image]

Any help in turning this into function will be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do:

```
x_df[, names_vec] <- 0

    var var1 XA101 XB101 XC101
1     a    a     0     0     0
2     a    a     0     0     0
3     a    a     0     0     0
4     a    a     0     0     0
5     a    a     0     0     0
6     a    a     0     0     0
7     a    a     0     0     0
8     a    a     0     0     0
9     a    a     0     0     0
10    a    a     0     0     0
```